# winapi OpenProcess always returning <read memory from 0x674 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)> and error 5 even with the corrent pid

Tags: rust, dll-injection

```
use winapi::um::processthreadsapi::{OpenProcess,CreateRemoteThreadEx};
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;
use winapi::shared::ntdef::NULL;
use winapi::um::winnt::{HANDLE,
    MEM_COMMIT, MEM_RELEASE, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
};

pub struct KernelObj {
    handle: HANDLE,
}

unsafe fn get_proccess(process_id: u32) -> Result<KernelObj, DWORD> {
    println!("inside get proccess => {}",process_id);
    let process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, process_id);
    if process == NULL {
        Err(GetLastError())
    } else {
        Ok(KernelObj{ handle: process })
    }
}
```

I am using rust winapi on windows 11 I am trying to do a process injection

whenever I tried to open explorer.exe it always returned this error
and it returning error 5

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3", features = ["winuser","errhandlingapi"] }
```

> <read memory from 0x674 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>

Edit => I Found that the code is still working but while debugging the debugger shows that error.